# UTF-8 JSON String parse with Node and make an array of objects

Tags: node.js, json, string, parsing

I have this data as a String of JSON Objects in to a file -format UTF-8.

I want to create an array of object out of it and query it, according to the keys it contains.

This is the data:

```
{
    "Number": "C",
    "Is": true,
    "ImageKey": "06",
    "image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAlgCWAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWNobm9sb2dpZXMgSW5jLiBWMS4wMQD/"
}{
    "Number": "A",
    "photoNot": false,
    "ImageKey": "61",
    "image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAlgCWAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWNobm9sb2dpZXMgSW5jLiBWMS4wMQD/"
}{
    "Number": "L",
    "photoIs": false,
    "ImageKey": "99",
    "image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAAEAlgCWAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWNobm9sb2dpZXMgSW5jLiBWMS4wMQD/"
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
const stringFile = fs.readFileSync('./test.json', 'utf-8')
const res = JSON.stringify(stringFile);

for (const json in stringFile) {

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)));

console.log(`Driver number of record is ${jsonData.ImageKey}`);
}
```

Expected result: value for ImageKey

Error: 
Unexpected token  in JSON at position 176
    at JSON.parse ()

Note! The second curly brace is underlined red in VS, message: EOF. json(0).

How can i fix this with code?

Comment: Ideea:

Since this is a JSON String with multiple objects str={object1}{object2}{object3}, we could consider '{object' = x ; '{}' = y ; find position y; json.parse(str)=substring(str, x, x-y); x+1;

Comment: What you're showing is not a JSON string. It's three JSON strings back-to-back, so: don't do that, make it a real JSON string by putting `[]` around that, with commas between them, and then just tell node to load it with `const yourdata = require('./yourfile.json')` because Node can natively read json and work with the resulting array of objects as normal.

Comment: What you have is [concatenated JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_streaming#Concatenated_JSON). You'll need to use a module like [concatjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concatjson) or [json-streaming-reader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-streaming-reader) to parse it safely. (Any answer that tells you to use `replace` or a similarly naive method to "transform" it into plain JSON is incorrect and will fail in a number of edge cases.)

Comment: or the process that produces `test.json` should be fixed to generate valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just import the JSON as plain old JS object?

```
const data = require('./test.json');

for (const d of data) {

    console.log(d);

    console.log(`Driver number of record is ${d.ImageKey}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Have you tested the code you posted here?